# Runtime Mobile Security - Error: Unable to communicate with remote frida-server

Tags: android, security, mobile, runtime, frida

I am having an error trying to communicate with the frida-server from RMS. Frida-server is already running but, when I try to access Runtime Mobile Security I am getting the following error:

> Device not connected. Please check your config and click here to try
> again. If you still see this error and the device is correctly
> connected with frida-server up and running, please kill RSM and start
> it again.
>
> Other possibile issues and solutions are described here: Notes and
> possibile issues.

So, when I try to reconnect, I receive the same message on RMS and also an error message on command line:

> Error: Unable to communicate with remote frida-server; please ensure
> that major versions match and that the remote Frida has the feature
> you are trying to use.

I currently have installed Frida v16.0.0 and it is running by MagiskFrida.

Phone is already connected by USB, frida-server is running. So, I tried everything but no idea what's the problem. May be the version?

When I try frida-ps -U, I can see all the processes running on my device. However, with the command "rms", I receive an IP address to runtime mobile security. There is where I see the first error: "Device not connected. Please check your config and click here to try again.
If you still see this error and the device is correctly connected with frida-server up and running, please kill RSM and start it again.
Other possibile issues and solutions are described here: Notes and possibile issues."

Comment: Please edit your question and include the Frida commands you execute.